# QGIS does not accept URL when I try to add a WFS layer

Tags: qgis, wfs

When I'm trying to add a WFS layer with this URL
"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_atkis-basis-dlm_aaa-modell-basiert?"
in QGIS, I get the error message "either the WFS server does not support version 1.0.0 or the URL is wrong". Then I tried it with the WFS 2.0 client, and getting the capabilities worked, but when I chose a feature type like "adv:AX_Wald" I get the error message "Download failed: Bad request" and it tells me that there is an error with the Python code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the built in WFS client, or the [WFS 2.0 plugin](https://github.com/JuergenWeichand/qgis-wfs20-client-plugin)?

Comment: the message seems to be correct "either the WFS server does not support version 1.0.0 or ..." The service doesn't report supporting version 1.0.0, you must use either WFS 1.1.0 or WFS 2.0.0 according to the service GetCapabilities response

Answer (score 2):

This particular WFS server responds with `Bad request` when you don't specify the correct CRS.
It supports only EPSG:25832 and EPSG:4258 (found out by fetching [GetCapabilities](https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_atkis-basis-dlm_aaa-modell-basiert?request=GetCapabilities&version=2.0&service=WFS)).

If you are using the [WFS 2.0 plugin](https://github.com/JuergenWeichand/qgis-wfs20-client-plugin), make sure to set it at the bottom of the dialog.